# DataContext IsLoading InvokeOperation

Tags: c#, silverlight, wcf-ria-services

I wanted to know if there is any way I can subscribe to a event that will tell me if an InvokeOperation is busy on the given DomainContext. Exactly like the IsLoading (which does not fire on InvokeOperation). At the Moment I've got:

```
DomainContext.PropertyChanged += (c1, c2) =>
                {
                    IsBusy = (DomainContext.IsLoading && DomainContext.IsSubmitting);
                };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) the code which you provide requires check of changed property name

```
DomainContext.PropertyChanged += (c1, c2) =>
                {
                  if(c2.PropertyName == "IsLoading" || c2.PropertyName == "IsSubmitting")
                    IsBusy = (DomainContext.IsLoading && DomainContext.IsSubmitting);
                };
```

2)DomainContext doesn't provide flag for invoke operation. But you always can set it yourself.

```
IsBusy = true;
DomainContext.InvokeMyOperation(c=>
                                    {
                                      //in callback
                                      IsBusy = false;
                                    });
```

Comment: Thanks, I've not yet put the check (c2.PropertyName == "IsLoading" || c2.PropertyName == "IsSubmitting") because I've got a breakpoint and I want to see what properties are called when in my domain context. Also, point (2) is what I am doing but I don't want to set the IsBusy property everytime I Invoke something at the risk of not setting it somewhere or when an exception is thrown it will still set the IsBusy back to false

Comment: if exception happens callback will be still invoked and you can unset busy flag. To avoid forgetfulness you can wrap this code into service class.

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping for an easier way to do it, I don't see why the IsLoading Property is not called with InvokeOperations